# FOR LOOP to make a image move diagonal

Tags: java, for-loop

I've been testing now for hours and can't seems it to work, I need some clues! What I want to do is to make a picture go from one edge to other diagonal. What do I have to do?

```
    PaintWindow window = new PaintWindow();
        ImageIcon man = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Barry/Desktop/DA339AP1HT14/gubbe.jpg");
        int leftRight = 1, rightLeft = 1;



        while (true){
            if (leftRight  > 0) {
            for (int x = 0; x <= 500; x += 10) {
                window.showImage(man, x, 0);
                PaintWindow.pause(50);


                }
            if (rightLeft > 0) {
                for (int x = 500; x >= 0; x -= 10) {
                    window.showImage(man, x, 300);
                    PaintWindow.pause(50);
                        {
                        }
                }
            }
                        }
}
    }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            uppgift1f e1f = new uppgift1f();
            e1f.leftRight();
    }
    }
```

EDIT ^^NEW

Just made it so it starts from left top and when it hits the right top then it changes down to right bottom to left bottom but now what I want to do is to make it diagonal and i have no idea how. Please help with suggestions!

Comment: you can't halt the main thread, gui won't refresh, schedule a timer to move the window periodically

Comment: PS: I deleted my comment after the edit. I was asking if the OP has the `main` inside `for (;;) { ... }`. However, this edit changed a lot.

Comment: @headsvk hmm thats strange, because i got it to work with side to side. (left to right) and then i used for(;;) to make it loop.

Comment: I think my problem is that i dont know how to combine a for loop with y and x. Which I think i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

i dont have the full code, but im going to assume that you have

```
window.showImage(picture,int Xcoord,int Ycoord);
```

so all you have to do is set both coodinates at the same time, like this:

```
window.showImage(man, X, X);
```

in your code:

```
while (true){
        if (leftRight  > 0) {
        for (int x = 0; x <= 500; x += 10) {
            window.showImage(man, x, x);
            PaintWindow.pause(50);
            }
```

or

```
for (int x = 0; x <= 500; x += 10) {
    for (int y = 0; y <= 500; y += 10) {
            window.showImage(man, x, y);
            PaintWindow.pause(50);
    }
}
```

Edit: 
if you want your ratio used: try so whats the ratio of your monitor? say you have xsize and ysize: 
int xsize = 500; int ysize = 800;

```
for (int x = 0; x <= xsize; x += 10 ) {
            window.showImage(man, x, x * ( ysize  /xsize));
            PaintWindow.pause(50);

}
```

Comment: Oh god! It worked! But it doesnt go from edge to edge, It starts with 0,0 but going to middle. Do i need to change in for (....) ?

Comment: It ends and going back from the top on left to here : 

http://i58.tinypic.com/2qa4up2.jpg

Comment: I tried the other one and it didnt go well, it just went from top to bottom. not diagnoal

Comment: sorry. im new to this. i editet the main, and gonna edit again. wait a minute :)

Comment: Maybe it will help you that the window is 600x400

Comment: It just went from top left to right, Is there somehow we could talk faster, like skype?

Comment: sure whats your skype?

Comment: Barryballer :) add me